# AtomicKotlin course adds additonal spaces and doesn't accept answers

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I'm doing Atomic Kotlin course and in one of the first exercises I get something like this:
[image: output comprison]
And this is my code:
[image: my solution for exercise]
It should accept my answer but it doesn't. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by going to build.gradle file and modifying printOutput from this:

```
def printOutput(def output) {
    return tasks.create("printOutput") {
        println "#educational_plugin_checker_version 1"
        def lines = output.toString().split("(?<=\n)|(?=\n)")
        for (line in lines) {
            println "#educational_plugin" + line
        }
    }
}
```

to this:

```
def printOutput(def output) {
    return tasks.create("printOutput") {
        def lines = output.toString().split("\n")
        for (line in lines) {
            println "#educational_plugin" + line
        }
    }
}
```